# laravel で select ボックスの値を維持したい

Tags: php, laravel

selectボックスでforを使って日付を今日から1週間分出すようにしてます。
入力ホームで値を維持させるための関数はoldを使っていました。

タイトルや本文は `value="{{ old('title') }}"` で引継ぐことができたのですが
selectをold関数でどのように表示させたらいいのかわかりません。

また、必須項目にしてバリデーションも追加したのですがそれもきちんと動いてくれません。

```
  <div style="display: flex">

    <div class="select_option">
      <div style="width: 300px">
        <select name="day" style="width: 300px; margin-bottom:10px">
          <option value="" disabled selected>日付</option>
          @for($i = 0; $i<=6; $i++)<option name="day" value="{{$day->addDay(1)}}">{{$day->format("Y年m月d日")}}</option>
            @endfor
        </select>
        @if($errors->has('date')) <p class="text-danger" style="font-size: 11px; margin:0">{{ $errors->first('date') }}</p> @endif
      </div>

      <div style="width: 300px">
        <select name="time" style="width: 300px">
          <option value="" disabled selected>時間</option>
          @for($i = 0; $i<=20; $i++) <option name="time" value="{{$time->addMinute(30)}}">{{$time->format("H:i")}}</option>
            @endfor
        </select>
        @if($errors->has('sendtime')) <p class="text-danger" style="font-size: 11px; margin:0">{{ $errors->first('sendtime') }}</p> @endif
      </div>
    </div>

<option value=""{{$day->addDay(1)}}" selected　@if(old('day')=='"{{$day->addDay(1)}}') selected  @endif>{{$day->format("Y年m月d日")}}</option>
```

のようにしてもダメでした。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$dayに対してaddDay()を実行すると$dayの値に加算されます。よって、if文内で比較するときにaddDay()を実行してしまうと、更に1日加算されてしまうので、ifがtrueになることは絶対に無いです。つまり、以下のようにすれば良いはずです。

```
<option
    value="{{ $day->addDay() }}"
    @if(old('day') === $day) selected @endif
>
{{ $day->format('Y年m月d日') }}
</option>
```

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。こちらのように入れてみたのですが登録して編集の先にやはりselectの値が維持されていませんでした。

Comment: ひとまず、bladeのほうで、old('day')に値が格納されているかどうかから見ていく必要がありそうですね。

Comment: もう一度教えていただいたコードで試してみたらいけました！ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

同じような箇所で詰まっていましたが、解決したので、共有します。
ご参考までに。

```
<select name="age" id="age">
   <option value="" disabled selected style='display: none;'>選択して下さい</option>
     @for ($i = 0; $i <= 50; $i++)
        <option value="{{ $i }}" @if(old('age')=="$i") selected @endif>{{ $i }} 
        </option>
     @endfor
   <option value="51" @if(old('age')=="51") selected @endif>50年以上</option>
</select>
```

Comment: アドバイスいただきありがとうございました！

```
<option value="" disabled selected style='display: none;'>日付</option>
@for($i = 0; $i<=6; $i++)<option name="day" value="{{$day->addDay(1)}}" @if(old('day')==="$day") selected @endif>{{$day->format("Y-m-d")}}</option>
@endfor
```